# Subtle Concept of pointers and array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference, pointer-arithmetic

I have a very strange example of pointers, which requires your kind help. In general, pointers are used to point to a variable (see first example below), but when it points to an array. I don't understand why it no longer requires deferencing to obtain the array (see second example below)

```
printf("TEST: %i\n", x[i]);// I expect this should be *x[i]
```

This is indeed very strange. Is it just a C convention or how do you explain this?

**EDIT:**:Since many have provided a clear answer, I want to include another small follow up question, as all of you mentioned x[i] = *(x+i), what about x[i][j] for a 2 dimensional array? what is it equivalent to ? Does it require dereferencing?

With a normal variable

```
int j = 4;
int* pointerj=&j;//pointerj holds address of j or points to j
printf("%d",*pointerj); returns the value that pointer j points to
```

With an array :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int *function(unsigned int tags) {
    int i;
    int *var;

    var = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*tags); // malloc is casted to int* type , allocated dynamical memory, it returns a pointer!
    //so now var holds the address to a dynamical array.

    for (i = 0; i < tags; i++) {
        var[i] = i;
    }

    return var;
}

int main() {
    int *x;
    int i;

    x = function(10);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("TEST: %i\n", x[i]);// I expect this should be *x[i]
    }

    free(x); x = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x[i]` is equivalent to `*(x + i)`.  So in fact, that means that one could write `*x` as `x[0]`.

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Oh! As a python programmer, i was completely mislead by this convention!! Cheers

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: A follow up question is that what about x[i][j] for a multi dimensional array? Is it equivalent to *(x+i+j)?

Comment: @elpsyCongroo I tried to expand my answer to cover this, please check.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Great, i hope beginners like me can find them all here and very useful!

Comment: @elpsyCongroo Cheers!! Glad I could be of help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *don't understand why it no longer requires dereferencing to obtain the array (element)*

Well, you **are** dereferencing, it's just not using the dereference operator `*`.

The array subscripting operator `[]` is serving as job of dereferencing here. quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.1

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]`
>   is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary `+` operator, if `E1` is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array object) and `E2` is an integer, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`-th
>   element of `E1` (counting from zero).

It's a syntactic sugar. The expressions `x[i]` and `*(x+i)` are equivalent. The later satisfies your expectation, whereas, the first one, disguises the dereference operator, but does the exact same job you expected.

---

That said, also follow the data type closely. What you were expecting, something along the line of `*x[i]` would be plain invalid, as it boils down to something like `*(*(x+i) ). Now,

- `x` is of type `int []` (integer array, which decays to a pointer to integer)
- `x+i` gives you a pointer to `int` type result.
- the inner dereference operator is applied to it, resulting an `int`.
- The outer `*`, now will try to operate on an operand of type `int` (not a pointer), and, this operation will be a syntactical error, as, the constraint for dereference operator says,

> The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.

in `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.2.

---

*Answering the additional question*:

Let me use the quote, once again, this one's from paragraph 2, chapter §6.5.2.1

> Successive subscript operators designate an element of a multidimensional array object.
>   If `E` is an `n`-dimensional array `(n ≥ 2)` with dimensions `i × j × . . . × k`, then `E` (used as
>   other than an lvalue) is converted to a pointer to an `(n − 1)`-dimensional array with
>   dimensions `j × . . . × k`. If the unary `*` operator is applied to this pointer explicitly, or
>   implicitly as a result of subscripting, the result is the referenced `(n − 1)`-dimensional
>   array, which itself is converted into a pointer if used as other than an lvalue. It follows
>   from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest).
>
> Consider the array object defined by the declaration
>
> ```
>   int x[3][5];
> ```
>
> Here `x` is a `3 × 5` array of `int`s; more precisely, `x` is an array of three element objects, each of which is an
>   array of five ints. In the expression `x[i]`, which is equivalent to `(*((x)+(i)))`, `x` is first converted to
>   a pointer to the initial array of five ints. Then `i` is adjusted according to the type of `x`, which conceptually
>   entails multiplying `i` by the size of the object to which the pointer points, namely an array of five `int`
>   objects. The results are added and indirection is applied to yield an array of five ints. When used in the
>   expression `x[i][j]`, that array is in turn converted to a pointer to the first of the ints, so `x[i][j]`
>   yields an `int`.

Comment: I am very sorry, could you explain in simpler words for this part? starting from , x is first converted to a pointer to the initial array of five ints. I'm lost..

Comment: @elpsyCongroo I'll surely try, please allow me some time, I'm a bit occupied now, I'll be back with a more non-formal explanation. That makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is ok. No * there.

If you have pointer `int *a` which points to array of valid data, for example:

```
int *a;
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a = arr;
```

By using `a[0]` you are already dereferencing pointer and `*` is not required as `a[0]` is the same as `*(a + 0)`.

---

You can go further and even more complicate code for readers.

You may use `i[x]` in your example instead of `x[i]`. Why?
`x[i]` is equal to `*(x + i)` but it is also equivalent to `*(i + x)` which is what arrays are in C.

It works even with numbers, such as `x[3]` or `3[x]` will give you the same result.

Answer (score 1):

In C, doing x[i] is equivalent (yeah I know) at i[x]. Your compiler compiles this by doing :

*(x+i), where you retrieve your favorite symbole.

x+i is a pointer where you start from x and advance by i. The result takes account of the type of the pointer (0xff is not the same address for a char* than for a int*).

Comment: what is this: *yeah I know*?

Comment: @Gaulois94 sorry, what does i[x] means? it confuses me now .. how can an index goes outside of the array? i is the index of the element of the array, right?

Comment: Just check what your compiler does. For him, x[i] is equivalent at *(x+i), and i[x] is equivalent at *(i+x). Both does the same : it takes x and advance in the memory by i.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how arrays work. Indeed, when using a variable such as `int` you should access it's address by

`int x;
 int *p2x = &x`

but when using array, it's a bit different. `int y[SOME_SIZE];` is a chunk of bytes in the memory, and `*y` will take you to the first element in that memory location, and dereference it. `y[0]` will do the same. `*y[0]` will first take the value in `y[0]` and then will try to dereference it... not what you usually want :(

Answer (score 1):

the simple answer to your question is that :

The name of array is pointer to first element of array.

Comment: @elpsyCongroo for sure it is true. If you use variable directly, then pointer to first element is used.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.